# Visual Studio 2022 Unable to read open Video file using cv::VideoCapture object

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2022

**Summary**

OpenV Exception raised when trying to open a video file using cv:VideoCapture object

Thought it might be a missing codec so tried to open different video file types but all failed. No luck.

**Code**

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void DisplayVideo()
{

    cout << "Display Video Mode Activated" << endl; 
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    VideoCapture cap;
    cap.open("Megamind.avi");
    if(cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Video file opened" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open Video file" << endl;
    }

}
```

**Error Message**

```
Display Video Mode Activated


[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\videoio_registry.cpp (223) cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(8, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (383) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 3 plugin(s) for FFMPEG
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64.dll => OK
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (50) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_capture_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (169) cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin': built with OpenCV 4.5 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.5.4' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (69) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (84) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_writer_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (169) cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin': built with OpenCV 4.5 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.5.4' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (103) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (383) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for GSTREAMER
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_gstreamer454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_gstreamer454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (383) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for INTEL_MFX
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_intel_mfx454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_intel_mfx454_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (383) cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 2 plugin(s) for MSMF
[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_msmf454_64d.dll => OK
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (50) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_capture_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (169) cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin': built with OpenCV 4.5 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.5.4' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (69) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (84) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_writer_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (169) cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin': built with OpenCV 4.5 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.5.4' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\backend_plugin.cpp (103) cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'Microsoft Media Foundation OpenCV Video I/O plugin'
[ INFO:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (788) CvCapture_MSMF::configureHW MSMF: Using D3D11 video acceleration on GPU device: AMD Radeon HD 7500/7600 Series
OpenCV(4.5.4) Error: Bad argument (CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): Megamind.avi) in cv::icvExtractPattern, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp, line 253
[ERROR:0] global C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.4) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): Megamind.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


We No fit open da Video file
[ INFO:1] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (74) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryRelease unload E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_msmf454_64d.dll
[ INFO:1] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (74) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryRelease unload opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64.dll

C:\Users\oldma\OneDrive\Coding\OpenCV\OReillyLearning\OReillyBook\x64\Debug\Switch.exe (process 9684) exited with code 0.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

**This is the output from cv::getBuildInformation()**

General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.4 =====================================
Version control:               4.5.4

Platform:
Timestamp:                   2021-10-09T17:02:31Z
Host:                        Windows 10.0.19041 AMD64
CMake:                       3.16.4
CMake generator:             Visual Studio 15 2017
CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft   Visual Studio/2017/Professional/MSBuild/15.0/Bin/MSBuild.exe
MSVC:                        1916
Configuration:               Debug Release

CPU/HW features:
Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
requested:                 SSE3
Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
AVX2 (30 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3   AVX AVX2
AVX512_SKX (5 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3   AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

C/C++:
Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
C++ standard:                11
C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft   Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe  (ver 19.16.27042.0)
C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP2  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /EHa /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4512 /wd4589 /MP2  /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe
C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP2   /MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP2 /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO
Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
ccache:                      NO
Precompiled headers:         NO
Extra dependencies:
3rdparty dependencies:

OpenCV modules:
To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo stitching video videoio world
Disabled:                    python2 python3
Disabled by dependency:      -
Unavailable:                 java ts
Applications:                apps
Documentation:               NO
Non-free algorithms:         NO

Windows RT support:            NO

GUI:
Win32 UI:                    YES
VTK support:                 NO

Media I/O:
ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
JPEG:                        build-libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.0-62)
WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.4.0)
OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
HDR:                         YES
SUNRASTER:                   YES
PXM:                         YES
PFM:                         YES

Video I/O:
DC1394:                      NO
FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
GStreamer:                   NO
DirectShow:                  YES
Media Foundation:            YES
DXVA:                      YES

Parallel framework:            Concurrency

Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

Other third-party libraries:
Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
at:                   C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/icv
Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
at:                C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_win/iw
Eigen:                       NO
Custom HAL:                  NO
Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

OpenCL:                        YES (NVD3D11)
Include path:                C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
Link libraries:              Dynamic load

Python (for build):            C:/utils/soft/python27-x64/python.exe

Java:
ant:                         C:/utils/soft/apache-ant-1.9.7/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.9.7)
JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_112/include
Java wrappers:               NO
Java tests:                  NO

Install to:                    C:/build/master_winpack-build-win64-vc15/install

Comment: I've fixed the formatting of your post. please look at what I changed to learn how to do this. -- Issue: it can't find your ffmpeg dll. `[ INFO:0] global c:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load E:\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64d.dll => FAILED` to hotfix this, find the DLL (I'm assuming it exists somewhere) and add the directory of that DLL to the `PATH` env var

Comment: Thanks ever so much Chris for the formatting.  
Thanks also for pointing me towards the missing files.  
Went through the log and the ff DLL's failed to load:  

opencv_videoio_ffmpeg454_64d.dll 
opencv_videoio_gstreamer454_64d.dll 
opencv_videoio_intel_mfx454_64d.dll 


Combed the directories and they are not present on my system so I am going to try to figure out how come I dont have them installed and get them onto my system

Comment: how did you install OpenCV? run `cout << cv::getBuildInformation()` and add the output to your post.

Comment: I downloaded the executable and run it.
This is as opposed to downloading the source code from the main repository and contrib
Trying to paste the results of cv:getBuildInformation() but I guess its too many characters for a comment.

I tried appending it to the original post and I was prompted that my post was mostly code. Trying to figure out a way to post the output from the command

Comment: the relevant section is the one with the video backends